# How to keep multiple variables with numbers in their names using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to make my code more elegant and I realized I may be doing some unnecessary coding. 
I have many variables entitled things like trust_1, trust_2, trust_3, etc. up to 25. 
I'm creating a new data frame made up of these variables in pandas.

```
df = df1[['trust_1', 'trust_2', 'trust_3', 'trust_4', 'trust_5' ]]
```

I was wondering if I could use regular expressions or something that takes the place of the number and will keep all the variables. 
For example,

```
df = df1[['trust_\d+']]
```

that would do the same thing as above. Is there a way?

Comment: Don't store everything in variables, use a data structure that's more appropriate.

Comment: You can use `df.filter(like='trust')`  or one of the many alternatives listed in the dupe. `.filter` also accepts regex. Check the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html)